# How to debug the write() function?

Tags: c, g++, cloud9-ide

I have an assignment where I can only use write to output results to the automatic evaluator. I haven't familiarized myself very well with write() and I am curious to know if there is an easy way to see what I am outputing through it.

(I have vs code and cloud9's IDE)

Comment: Where are you actually writing to? What is an "automatic elevator" in this context? If you want to see what is being written then the easiest way is to look in the destination location. Or use a debugger and put a breakpoint on `write` or on line before `write` is called so that you can inspect the buffer contents.

Comment: To test your program, run it directly as an executable on your own system, so the output goes to your terminal window or a file as you direct. Once it is tested, then you can submit it to the evaluator.

Comment: @kaylum: They are writing to an output stream that is a pipe or file that is read by software that grades the assignment. The execution of the program by that software may be not under their control and not accessible through a debugger during that execution.

Comment: @kaylum I think you might have misread my post, it is not an elevator its an _*evaluator*_ aka automatic grading system. And I have no Idea where it is writing to.

Comment: My apologies, I did misread that. But it is still not clear what the exact set up is. Please show your code. Specifically where/how it gets the file descriptor to write to. In any case, the advice to use a debugger still applies - putting a break point before the write will allow you to examine the write buffer. And if you show us your code we may be able to tell you more specifically how to get the output to show on the terminal.